# creating link of a heading with underscore in md file

Tags: github-flavored-markdown

I am trying to create a link for heading (with underscore) in my markdown file. e.g.

`# MY_MACRO_NAME`

I have tried with following pattern but no success, any idea ?

`[MY_MACRO_NAME](#MY_MACRO_NAME)` `[MY_MACRO_NAME](MY_MACRO_NAME)`
`[MY_MACRO_NAME](#MY-MACRO-NAME)` `[MY_MACRO_NAME](#my_macro_name)`
`[MY_MACRO_NAME](#my-macro-name)` `[MY_MACRO_NAME](#MYMACRONAME)`

Comment: Found the Working link  [MY_MACRO_NAME](#mymacroname)

Comment: That's just for intellij, In github it takes underscore.